What does the と do in ときめる？
Is と used before きめる the same way it would be used in という、とおもう？ For example in the following sentence, 彼は夜ご飯を食べないと決めていると聞きましあ, why does it say ときめている？ What is the と doing before the verb きめている？

Particles aren't used before words at all. They're used after words. When we say Xと言うY, the と isn't modifying 言う, but X. Therefore, the grammar doesn't depend on whether the verb is [言]{い}う or [思]{おも}う or [決]{き}める or anything else.
However, this と is indeed quotative, just as it commonly is when followed by 言う or 思う. That isn't a grammar point about those verbs; it's a consequence of the fact that it makes sense to use those verbs with quotations.
The Japanese concept of "quotation" in the sense of particle-と is much more flexible than implied by that English term - and here it's used twice, so it's nested. There is hearsay about someone's choice not to eat dinner. (I don't know whether 彼は should apply to the inner quotation or the outer one.) Some verbs are more amenable to this than others, but I still don't like the idea of describing と as "before the verb" since it's not the verb that gets inflected this way.
決める is transitive, so I think 夜ご飯を食べないと決めているcould be rephrased as 夜ご飯を食べない事を決めている (notice that it requires nominalization).
But using quotative-と like this is idiomatic, and it helps cue the sentence structure (dealing with multiple を's is considerably harder).
